# Pop camera or video capture options from Android HTML5 based app used with Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, uploadify

I have an android app I developed using the cordova framework using HTML5 for the interface.  I have a form with a file input tag used to grab photos or videos from the device.  In the Ios version, clicking this button pops a dialogue where you can select to capture a pic or video, which is then used by the app.

However, in the android version, the file browser dialogue pops with no options to capture direct. This is my problem.  I want to be able to have the pic and video capture options displayed.

I subsequently use uploadifive to send some text and the selected media(video or pic) to a server.

When I do this from the web version of this form, using the android browser, both video and picture capture options appear and work great.

In the app I have tried using the capture options in the file input tag as follows:

```
<input type="file"  name="image" id="image" accept="image/*; capture=camera" />
```

But this is not working either.

Comment: You appear to be missing the code it looks like you intended to add.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use cordova's capture event for camera to work. Check cordova documentation.